# Whenever ruby scheduler doesn't work, what am I missing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, scheduling, whenever

Cannot make it works ...

In my config/schedule.rb I have :

```
set :output, '../log/development.log'

every 5.minutes do
  runner "UserWatchedRepo.update"
end
```

Note the log setted, but nothing happen. In my Rails 3.0.10 model file app/models/user_watched_repo.rb I get :

```
class UserWatchedRepo
  include Mongoid::Document

  def update
    conn = FaradayStack.build 'https://api.github.com'
    User.all.map do |user| 
      nickname = user.nickname
      resp = conn.get "/users/#{nickname}/watched"

      resp.body.each do |repo|
        user.watchlists.build( html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
                               description: "#{repo['description']}",
                               fork_: "#{repo['fork']}",
                               forks: "#{repo['forks']}",
                               watchers: "#{repo['watchers']}",
                               created_at: "#{repo['created_at']}",
                               pushed_at: "#{repo['pushed_at']}",
                               avatar_url: "#{repo['owner']['avatar_url']}" )
      end
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea ?

Thank you 
Luca

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you run the `whenever` - command in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run the `whenever` command in your console?

Your code doesn't actually create a cronjob, it just provides the inputdata for the whenever gem which has to be turned into an actual cronjob.

To get this done, you have to `cd` into your apps root directory and run the following command:

```
whenever --update-crontab YOUR_APP_NAME
```

As far as I know, `YOUR_APP_NAME` doesn't have to be your actual app name, it has just to be a unique identifier. I consider it good practice though to use your appname to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you use some sort of deployment solution, I'd also recommend throwing a `whenever --update-crontab` task in it to be executed prior to restarting the server. Simplifies things in the long run.

Comment: I'm on heroku is that possible too ?

Comment: @klaffenboeck ... do you mean it is unix cron wrapper ? Can you suggest a Rails 'embeddable' self contained solution, to deploy on heroku ?

Comment: @LucaG.Soave : I am sorry, but I doubt that there is a free solution that will fit your needs. You can try to run the command in the heroku console, but I doubt, that it will work, since hourly cronjobs are something you have to pay extra for on heroku (see [http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron) ). Sorry if this is not the answer you were hoping for.